# Java Spark: How to get value from a column which is JSON formatted string for entire dataset?

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Needs some help here. I am trying to read data from Hive/CSV. There is a column whose type is string and the value is json formatted string. It is something like this:

```
|                      Column Name A                       |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|"{"key":{"data":{"key_1":{"key_A":[123]},"key_2":[456]}}}"|
```

How can I get the value of key_2 and insert it to a new column?

I tried to create a new function to the get value via Gson

```
private BigDecimal getValue(final String columnValue){
    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(columnValue).getAsJsonOBject();
    return jsonObject.get("key").getAsJsonObject().get("key_1").getAsJsonObject().get("key_2").getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsBigDecimal();
}
```

But how i can apply this method to the whole dataset?

I was trying to achieve something like this:

```
Dataset<Row> ds = souceDataSet.withColumn("New_column", getValue(sourceDataSet.col("Column Name A")));
```

But it cannot be done as the data types are different...

Could you please give any suggestions?

Thx!
hx!

------------------Update---------------------

As @Mck suggested, I used get_json_object.
As my value contains `"`

```
"{"key":{"data":{"key_1":{"key_A":[123]},"key_2":[456]}}}"
```

I used substring to removed `"` and make the new string like this

```
{"key":{"data":{"key_1":{"key_A":[123]},"key_2":[456]}}}
```

Code for substring

```
DataSet<Row> dsA = sourceDataSet.withColumn("Column Name A",expr("substring(Column Name A, 2, length(Column Name A))"))
```

I used `dsA.show()` and confirmed the dataset looks correct.

Then I used following code try to do it

```
Dataset<Row> ds = dsA.withColumn("New_column",get_json_object(dsA.col("Column Name A"), "$.key.data.key_2[0]"));
```

which returns `null`.

However, if the data is this:

```
{"key":{"data":{"key_2":[456]}}}
```

I can get value 456.

Any suggestions why I get null?
Thx for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_json_object`:

```
ds.withColumn(
    "New_column",
    get_json_object(
        col("Column Name A").substr(lit(2), length(col("Column Name A")) - 2),
        "$.key.data.key_2[0]")
).show(false)

+----------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|Column Name A                                             |New_column|
+----------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|"{"key":{"data":{"key_1":{"key_A":[123]},"key_2":[456]}}}"|456       |
+----------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: HI Mck, Thx for your help! As you suggested I used get_json_object. However, it returns null for me. If I removed key_1 and its value fromt the string, it works. Any suggestions? I have updated the original question.

Comment: @Lehtia could you show the code you used to remove the quotes? just want to make sure that is done correctly

Comment: @Lehtia I included a code for using `substr` - see if that works for you?

Comment: Hi @mck, I have updated the orignal question. I used expr to get the substring. And used dataset.show() to confirm it is removed. Thx!

Comment: @Lehtia apparently, only the beginning quote is removed, but the ending quote remains. Then the json query fails because the json string is malformed. I think it should be `length(Column Name A) -1`

Comment: HI msc, you are kinds of right. I finally found the issue which casued incorrect json. In my case, The length of the column is 268. But length function only gives me 68 as csv file formate is totally wrong and I actually cannot load the raw file fully. But your solution is totoally working well. Thx for the help!